# Access fields in Django

Tags: python, django, field, conditional-statements

The problem is, when i'm trying to compare two properties which are the same when we check them in shell, but the condition is not complete and i have no idea why. I mean this condition: {% if c.author = member.name %}

views:

```
    cvs = Cv.objects.all()
    cv = Cv.objects.filter(author = request.user)
    per = Person.objects.all()
    gr = Group.objects.filter(members__name=request.user)

    for c in cvs:
        print c.author

    mem = Membership.objects.all()
    form = GroupForm()


    context = {
        'gr': gr,
        'per':per,
        'mem':mem,
        'form': form,
        'cvs':cvs,
        'cv':cv,
    }

    return render(request, 'groups.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class Cv(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null = True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=25, null = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    telephone = models.IntegerField()
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
    skills = models.TextField(null=True)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    interests = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)


    @property
    def age(self):
        return int((datetime.datetime.now().date() - self.birth_date).days / 365.25 )

    def zapisz(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.surname




class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

     def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

groups.html:

```
{% block profile %}


      {% for g in gr %}
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <p><b>GROUP:</b> {{g.name}}</p>
          {% for c in cvs %}
            {% for member in g.members.all %}
              {% if c.author = member.name %}
                {{member.name}}
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}



{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please give your variables descriptive names. "c" and "gr" are impossible to understand.

Secondly, you are not comparing the right things at all. `c.author` is an instance of User; `member` is an instance of Person and `member.name` is a string. Comparing a User instance with a string will always fail.

Finally, this whole thing is *horribly* inefficient - and probably totally unnecessary. Three nested for loops means a huge number of iterations. If you could explain what the output needs to be, then we can almost certainly come up with a better way of doing it.

Comment: Well, when i got this code:           {% for g in gr %}
            <div class="jumbotron">
              <p><b>GROUP:</b> {{g.name}}</p>
              {% for member in g.members.all %}
                    <p><b>Member:</b> {{member.name}}</p>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          {% endfor %}.
I got what i want, i mean, i wanna display all groups, and then, in every other group, all users which are included. I got this with this code above, but i got only name's of the users - cv.authors - then they are oryginall and they can not be substitute.

Comment: But i want to make them links to theirs profiles. For example: <p><b>Member:</b> <a href="{% url "proj.views.cv_detail" pk=cv.pk %}">{{cv.name}} {{cv.surname}}</a> </p>. Thats why i'm just using here Cv model.

Answer (score 1):

To test for equality in a Django template you need to use the equality operator `==` as follows:

```
 {% if c.author == member.name %}
     {{member.name}}
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: still the same output - nothing. Only groups are displaying all the time, nothing more :/

Comment: Output `{{ c.author }}` and `{{ member.name }}` above the test for equality to visualise what they are and if they are equal

Comment: Yes, i test them like: '{% for c in cvs %}
              <p> First output: {{c.author}} </p>
              {% endfor %}
              {% for member in g.members.all %}
              <p>Second output: {{member.name}} </p>
                {% endfor %}'
 And the output is: 'First output: zahi

First output: damian

First output: test

First output: kacper

Second output: damian

Second output: kacper'

So there are the same when i mean name "kacper"

Comment: So there will be no output because `zahi != damian` and `damian != kacper`

Comment: Of course, but the loop can go a little further, and kacper == kacper could be possible in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare c.name with member.name or c.author.first_name with member.name. So both of the variable to be strings.

Comment: Didn't work, becouse if we pick c.name, we'll get 'Damian', and the member.name is 'damian', so they are not the same. Both metods which u entered didn't work. Output is empty

Comment: can you use {%  c.name|upper == member.name|upper %)  (untried)